# Multer returning req.file as undefined when uploading a single file

Tags: javascript, express, multer

I have looked extensively through previous questions about this topic, but the solutions to them usually involve the html form not having an enctype.

Here's the html form

```
<form action='/profile' method='post'enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="photo">Image</label>
  <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" accept="image/*" required>
  <input type='submit' value='Upload!' />
</form>
```

Here's the multer setup

```
//Local Storage
var storage =  multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, callback) {
callback(null, './uploads');
},
filename: function (req, file, callback) {
callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
}
});

var upload = multer({ storage : storage});
```

And finally my (simplified) post route

```
router.post("/profile",upload.single('photo'),middleware.isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
if(!req.file){
  console.log(req);
  console.log("Did not work");
}else{
  console.log(req.file);
  }
}
});
```

As requested here is the middleware I am using

```
middlewareObject.isLoggedIn = function(req,res,next){
 if(req.isAuthenticated()){
   return next();
 }else{
  res.redirect("/login")
 }
}
```

Anybody have any ideas as to what may be wrong? I think that this is a problem with multer not successfully uploading the image, but I can't seem to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code locally and it seems to work for me. Here's the snippet I ran:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        console.log('File: ' + file)
        callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.post('/profile', upload.single('photo'), function(req, res) {
    if(!req.file) {
        console.log(req);
        console.log("Did not work");
    } else {
        console.log(req.file);
    }
});
```

I can see `req.file` fine. I see you're using a middleware, have you checked your middleware code as well? Also, it would help if you can post your middleware snippet as well.

Comment: Thank you for running it locally. Perhaps it does have to do with my middleware. I added the code from the middleware file to the original post.

Comment: Just for sanity's sake, if you remove the middleware, does it work for you?

Comment: I removed the middleware from my POST route, and it did not work, so the issue may not be related to that.

Comment: Then I would probably need to see the whole file. Something else may be going on.

Comment: Also, one thing you may not doing is not using `body-parser`. Here's what I am doing:

`
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
})); 
`

Comment: Ah okay, I have read that body-parser may cause conflicts with multer. I was indeed using bodeparser, and had extended set to true. I tried setting it to false but got the same result.

Comment: Okay wooow I figured out the issue. I was using a package called express-fileupload that I forgot to remove from my app.js. Apparently it puts all of the uploaded files into req.files, even if I am uploading a single file. Thank you for bearing with me!

Comment: No problem! Glad I was able to help a bit.